# Numpy: mean calculation results in nan values

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, nan

I have an array of values x:

```
 x=numpy.array([[-0.11361818  -0.113618185  -0.98787775  -0.09719566],
 [-0.11361818  -0.04173076 -0.98787775  -0.09719566],
 [-0.11361818  -0.04173076 -0.98787775  -0.09719566],
 [-0.62610493  -0.71682393 -0.24673653  -0.18242028],
 [-0.62584854  -0.71613061 -0.24904998  -0.18287883],
 [-0.62538661  -0.71551038 -0.25160676  -0.18338629]])
```

and an array of corresponding classes labels y:

```
y=numpy.array([1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4])
```

The first class label 1 in y belongs to the first row in array x, the second class label 1 in y belongs to the second row in array x and so on.

Now I want to calculate the mean values for each class 1-4. For example, row 1 and 2 in x both belong to class 1, so I calculate the mean of row 1 and 2.

I have the following code:

```
means = numpy.array([x[y == i].mean(axis=0) for i in xrange(4)])
```

When I do this I end up with this result:

```
array([[        nan],
       [-1.27636606],
       [-1.24042235],
       [-1.77208567]])
```

If I take xrange(6), I have this result:

```
array([[        nan],
       [-1.27636606],
       [-1.24042235],
       [-1.77208567],
       [-1.774899  ],
       [        nan]])
```

Why is this the case and how do I get rid off the nans and end up with my 4 mean values only?

I have the code from  [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/mixture/plot_gmm_classifier.html), where they took the number of classes as argument for xrange(), and I don't quite see what I did differently.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`xrange(4)` results in the values `[0, 1, 2, 3]`. Your first value in `means` is `nan` because you don't have a `y` value equal to zero.

Instead, do:

```
In [49]: means = numpy.array([x[y == i].mean(axis=0) for i in xrange(1, 5)])

In [50]: means
Out[50]: 
array([[-1.27636606],
       [-1.24042235],
       [-1.77208567],
       [-1.774899  ]])
```